# How to remove elements?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I created an example of my problem in jsfiddle, when I click the minus symbol it always seems to remove the last element in the list.

Steps to reproduce:

- Press add 3 times
- Select different options in each
- press middle minus button

The last one is always deleted, expected behaviour is that the dropdown inline with the minus button is removed.

html

```
<!-- index.html -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<title>React Tutorial</title>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.7/react.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.7/react-dom.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-core/5.8.23/browser.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/marked/0.3.2/marked.min.js"></script>
<body>
<div id="content"></div>
<script src="main2.jsx" type="text/babel"/>
</body>
```

jsx

```
var ConditionGroup = React.createClass({

    makeId: function () {
        return Math.floor((Math.random() * 10000000000000) + 1);
    },

    getInitialState: function () {
        return {conditionNodes: []};
    },

    removeCondition: function(condition) {
        let res = [];
        console.log(condition);
        console.log(this.state.conditionNodes);
        for (var i = 0; i < this.state.conditionNodes.length; i++) {
            if (this.state.conditionNodes[i].props.id !== condition.props.id) {
                console.log('beep');
                res.push(this.state.conditionNodes[i]);
            }
        }
        console.log(res);

        this.setState({conditionNodes: res});
    },

    handleAddCondition: function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var conditionNodes = this.state.conditionNodes;
        conditionNodes.push(
            (
                <Condition removeCondition={this.removeCondition} id={this.makeId()}/>
            )
        );

        this.setState({conditionNodes: conditionNodes});
    },

    render: function () {
        return (
            <div className="conditionGroup">
                {this.state.conditionNodes}

                <br/>
                <input onClick={this.handleAddCondition} type="button" value="Add"/>
            </div>
        )
    }
});

var Condition = React.createClass({
    conditions: [
        {id: "STATE", name: "State"},
        {id: "PATTERN_MATCH", name: "Pattern Match"},
        {id: "GREATER_THAN", name: "Greater Than"},
        {id: "LESS_THAN", name: "Less Than"},
        {id: "EQUAL_TO", name: "Equal To"},
        {id: "IS_TRUE", name: "Is True"}
    ],

    getInitialState: function () {
        return {selectValue: "STATE"}
    },

    handleRemoveAction: function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        this.props.removeCondition(this);
    },

    onChange: function (e) {
        this.setState({selectValue: e.target.value})
    },

    render: function () {
        var conditionOptions = this.conditions.map(function (condition) {
            return (
                <option value={condition.id}>{condition.name}</option>
            )
        });

        return (
            <div class="condition">
                <select onChange={this.onChange} value={this.state.selectValue}>
                    {conditionOptions}
                </select>

                <input onClick={this.handleRemoveAction} value="-" type="button"/>
            </div>
        )
    }
});

ReactDOM.render(
    <ConditionGroup/>,
    document.getElementById('content')
);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/sd3h7g3v/

Comment: Don't store elements in the state. Rather, just store simple `id` or the `value` of each dropdown.

Comment: Actually if you print the is before minus button and observe, the actual node is getting removed while you click corresponding button. But the problem is the values also getting re-rendered in order. Hence if you delete 3rd dropdown, 4th dropdown is displaying 3rd dropdown value, 5th does 6th and so on.... Have to look at this. But the approach you taken is too complicated, could have been simpler

Comment: Also, if you do `var conditionNodes = this.state.conditionNodes;` and then
`conditionNodes.push(...)`, you are directly mutating state, which you should not do.